# Migrating SQL Server 2008 DB to Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I would like to migrate a SQL Server 2008 database to Postgres.

Is there a painless way to do this? are there any tools that will scan through the schema and stored procedures to flag compatibility problems?

Answer (score 1):

1. Painless http://dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-postgre-pro.php
2. Painfull export plain schema + regex + rewrite tsql.

Comment: I think a tool like that can give you a starting point. You should however still go through all your stored procedures to make sure thinks work correctly on the new database. SQL Server 2008 is not PostgreSQL and I have yet to see a conversion tool do a 100% job at understanding all the diffrences between two database systems, such as locking model. That said I have never used this tool.